# Sharing code between NSDocument and UIDocument

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsdocument

I have created a document-based app that uses Core Data. I created the mac version first, and now that it's working properly, I am moving on to create an iOS version of it.

I just can't get my head around how to maximize code reuse between the iOS/mac versions, with respect to the Core data bit, since they don't use the same classes.

My document class that handles saving and such is a subclass of `NSPersistentDocument`. My intention is that a well-designed model class should work in both environments, especially since I don't do all that much fancy stuff with regards to Core data.

Now, since `NSPersistentDocument` isn't available in iOS, I hit a wall. I tried to get around this by using `#if TARGET_OS_MAC and TARGET_OS_IPHONE` and in that manner make it a subclass of `UIManagedDocument` in the iOS version. That obviously would have been convenient, but I can't seem to make it work like that. And it's really looks quite messy, since there are a lot of other stuff that has to be conditionalized as well.

I also tried building the classes atop of `NSDocument`/`UIDocument` instead, implementing the Core data hooks myself, but it also looks quite messy, leaving me thinking it's not the right way to go.

**The question:**

To me, it seems like a good idea to reuse the same document class between the iOS/mac versions, but maybe I'm being naive.

What's the best way to do this?

Should I forget about the code sharing and create a separate document class for the iOS version that emulates all the methods present in the mac version?

Comment: I can't speak to this specific scenario, but it might be helpful to consider the general case: you have two classes that must inherit from different superclasses, but you have code you want to share between them. The usual answer to such (in ObjC) is composition: put the shared code into a different class, and reference an instance of that class from both.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. Please post is an answer, and I'll pick it. One follow-up question though, it seems like I'm writing 20-30 methods in my composite object that only forwards them to the exact same method on the specialized receiver. Is there any nicer way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Bringing this over from my comment.)

In general, the situation where you have two classes which must inherit from different superclasses but which also want to share a lot of code is *composition*. Put the shared code in a separate class; your `NSDocument` and `UIDocument` subclasses can each keep an instance of that class, and message it whenever they need to invoke that shared code. (Though as @noa mentions, you might want to consider whether all of that code belongs in your document class to begin with.)

Of course, then you might end up writing a bunch of methods that read like:

```
- (id)doSomething {
    return [sharedController doSomething]
}
```

That can get to be a pain... so you might want to look into Objective-C's [message forwarding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html) system.

Comment: Note to future readers: I picked this as the answer to the question, but I had to abandon it in my particular case after it became apparent that there's a lot of forwarding methods that needs to be written and kept up to date. Instead I went with keeping separate classes for the iOS and mac implementations, as it seemed more practical.

Answer (score 3):

Am I right that the code you're wanting to share is model-related? I suggest refactoring that code to a separate object, which both an `NSDocument` and `UIDocument` contain (as rickster suggested above).

I use a `DocumentRoot` Core Data entity with its own `NSManagedObject` subclass, but if there are no properties you want to manage using Core Data, you can just subclass `NSObject`.

This may sound strange, but `NSDocument` and `UIDocument` are actually controller classes. (To be specific, they're part of the model-controller.) Their jobs are to load the model, set up windows, and save the model. If you need to provide an interface for higher-level access to model objects, it could be in a document root or model helper class instead.

Similarly `NSPersistentDocument`'s job is to configure the managed object context and the persistent store and handle loading and saving. It doesn't necessarily need to provide a complete interface for accessing the model.